# VS Code python debugger won't stop at breakpoint in a multithread application

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I just reinstalled vs code because my debugger was messing up the current line and step into didn't work correctly. Now all of a sudden I have a bigger problem. The debugger won't stop at my breakpoints at all.
It is a multi thread application but to my knowledge that shouldn't be a problem for the vs code debugger. Furthermore, it worked before the reinstall. Did anyone encounter a similar problem with vs code and the python debugger. I'm quite clueless. This is so weird.
My debug config is the same as before and the only package in use is Python at the moment. So it can't be a problem with this.

Comment: Is sys.settrace involved anywhere? I ran into issues debugging tests with coverage (which usually involve sys.settrace). This cased breakpoints to be skipped.

Comment: Yes it is. But it was before too. The multi threading isn't my code, so it's difficult to change

Comment: Can you share the related code with us if it's convenient. also your machine parameter, like OS, python version, used extension.

Comment: Sharing these links for references. I know they are about testing, but they indicate that sys.settrace may cause debugging breakpoints to be skipped in VSCode, PyCharm, etc.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/693
https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debuggers.html

Comment: Another option that VS Code gives, in launch.json set "justMyCode": false. VSCode gives this hint when you hover over the breakpoint in the "breakpoints" window while stopped in debugger.